# rollback test transactions in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Working on some basic tests, I discovered that I cannot ROLLBACK a transaction inside a PLPGSQL function for I get an error:

```
ERROR:  cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL
HINT:  Use a BEGIN block with an EXCEPTION clause instead.
```

So I instead do:

```
RAISE EXCEPTION "Test passed";
```

Does anyone have a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in PostgreSQL not allow commit or rollback operation inside , just can do it in procedure from versión 11. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-transactions.html

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you raise a exception, then `ROLLBACK` to near safepoint is called automatically.

Against to other databases, is not necessary (possible) to handle transactions manually.